# I do not have the same rendering with elements created dynamically - JQuery - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap and Jquery for my website, and I have a issue.
When I create elements dynamically, I don't have the same rendering as my 'static' elements, that's my html elements :

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
    <button type="button" class="action btn btn-default">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="action btn btn-default">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

That's the rendering : 
[image: That's the rendering]

And that's the rendering, when I click on the Add button :

[image: New buttons added but they don't have space between them]

I don't know why the rendering is like that because I have put the same html element in my Add button listenner :

```
        $("#btnAddBuild").click(function(){
        var htmlContent = "<div class='row' style='margin-bottom: 10px;'>" +
                                "<div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-2'>" +
                                    "<button type='button' class='action btn btn-default'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></span></button>" +
                                    "<button type='button' class='action btn btn-default'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button>" +
                                "</div>" +
                            "</div>"
        //console.log(htmlContent);
        $("#rowListBuilds").append(htmlContent);
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: can you add the add button in your code?

Comment: The difference is in the whitespace. Your original version has a gap between buttons due to the line break. The jQuery appended version is built as a continuous string. The easiest fix is to just add a space between buttons in the string you build.

Comment: You're alright @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the static html markup, there are multiple space characters between the buttons(which is collapsed to a single space), but in the string literal used for the dynamic elements there is no space.

Just add a `[space]` character between the button elements

```js
 $("#btnAddBuild").click(function() {
   var htmlContent = "<div class='row' style='margin-bottom: 10px;'>" +
     "<div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-2'>" +
     "<button type='button' class='action btn btn-default'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></span></button> " +
     "<button type='button' class='action btn btn-default'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button>" +
     "</div>" +
     "</div>"
     //console.log(htmlContent);
   $("#rowListBuilds").append(htmlContent);
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rowListBuilds"></div>
<button id="btnAddBuild">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem once and solved it by building the template string with linebreaks (via newline "\n"):

```
 $("#btnAddBuild").click(function(){
        var htmlContent = ["<div class='row' style='margin-bottom: 10px;'>",
                                "<div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-2'>",
                                    "<button type='button' class='action btn btn-default'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></span></button>",
                                    "<button type='button' class='action btn btn-default'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button>",
                                "</div>",
                            "</div>"].join("\n")
        //console.log(htmlContent);
        $("#rowListBuilds").append(htmlContent);
    });
```

So the browser does not get a single line string to display but a multiliner, as if you would type it yourself in HTML.

Check it out:
https://jsfiddle.net/np9m8gse/